# Why can't I copy executables like this?

Tags: c++, copy, fstream

Using C++'s `<fstream>`, it's pretty easy to copy a text file:

```
#include <fstream>

int main() {
    std::ifstream file("file.txt");
    std::ofstream new_file("new_file.txt");

    std::string contents;
    // Store file contents in string:
    std::getline(file, contents);
    new_file << contents; // Write contents to file

    return 0;
}
```

But when you do the same for an executable file, the output executable doesn't actually work. Maybe std::string doesn't support the encoding?

I was hoping that I could do something like the following, but the file object is a pointer and I'm not able to dereference it (running the following code creates new_file.exe which actually just contains the memory address of something):

```
std::ifstream file("file.exe");
std::ofstream new_file("new_file.exe");

new_file << file;
```

I would like to know how to do this because I think it would be essential in a LAN file-sharing application. I'm sure there are higher level APIs for sending files with sockets, but I want to know how such APIs actually work.

Can I extract, store, and write a file bit-by-bit, so there's no discrepancy between the input and output file? Thanks for your help, it's much appreciated.

Comment: You need to pass `std::ios::binary` for the `openmode` argument of the stream constructors. And the best way of bulk-copying the contents of one stream to another is `new_file << file.rdbuf();`.

Comment: An `std:string` is text -- not binary data. Binary data can be represented by a `vector<uint8>` or a `basic_string<uint8>`. Try that.

Comment: @Linuxios : `std::string` can contain any `char` value, so it's quite capable of holding binary data; the problem here is the streams performing line-ending conversions.

Comment: @ildjarn: I thought that `std::string` restricted it to UTF-8 values (at least on some implementations). Thanks for the information. I still think it makes more sense to store binary data in a `vector<uint8>` or `basic_string<uint8>`. It's just clearer about the intentions and content of the file.

Comment: @ildjarn: And those conversions are system-specific. On Linux, for example, you probably *can* copy binary files using text operations; on Windows, reading a binary file as if it were text will likely translate CR-LF pairs to just LF, and possibly treat any occurrence of character 26 (control-Z) as an end-of-file indicator.

Comment: @Linuxios `std::string` has no idea that UTF-8 even exists. It's just a bunch of bytes strung together.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes is right; if you want Unicode, use `std::u16string` (UTF-16) or `std::u32string` (UTF-32) ;-)

Comment: @oldrinb I don't see how that helps if you want Unicode. All three are just containers of code units. The fact that `std::string` doesn't know about UTF-8 doesn't mean you can't use it for that. But this is getting off-topic now.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes `char16_t` will be able to store any character from the BMP, which is going to make it far more usable for dealing with common Unicode (see Java's `String`).

Comment: @oldrinb : As opposed to `char` and UTF-8?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not sure why ildjarn made it a comment, but to make it an answer (if he posts an answer, I will delete this). Basically, you need to use *unformatted* reading and writing. `getline` formats the data.

```
int main()
{
    std::ifstream in("file.exe", std::ios::binary);
    std::ofstream out("new_file.exe", std::ios::binary);

    out << in.rdbuf();
}
```

Technically, `operator<<` is for formatted data, *except* when use it like the above.

Answer (score 2):

In very basic terms:

```
using namespace std;

int main() {
    ifstream file("file.txt", ios::in | ios::binary );
    ofstream new_file("new_file.txt", ios::out | ios::binary);

    char c;
    while( file.get(c) ) new_file.put(c);

    return 0;
}
```

Although, you'd be better off making a char buffer and using `ifstream::read` / `ofstream::write` to read and write chunks at a time.